# Как удалить весь текст после точки?

Tags: c#

Пример строки -

string g = "Все автомобили, работающие на дизеле и бензине, должны исчезнуть с улиц норвежской столицы к 2035 году. С такой инициативой выступила Норвежская рабочая партия, предоставив проект документа по охране окружающей среды в Осло.";

Как мне удалить текст после точки?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Лень посмотреть какие методы есть у String или проблема в составлении плана их применения? / Найдите позицию точки (.indexof()) и потом используйте .substr() для получения части строки от начала до точки.

Comment: Да я начал программить месяца два как. Искал ну ничего похожего не нашел.

Comment: Понятно. Лучше прочтите для начала какой-нибудь систематический учебник по программированию. От  учебы без понимания основ обработки данных с помощью поиска сомнительных примеров и   дурацких вопросов толку все равно не будет (составлять алгоритмы и строить правильные структуры данных Вы так не научитесь).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string text = @"Все автомобили, работающие...";
int dotIndex = text.IndexOf('.');
if (dotIndex >= 0)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, dotIndex + 1);
}
```

Если нужно отсекать по нескольким знакам - можно использовать `IndexOfAny`:

```
int dotIndex = text.IndexOfAny(new char[]{ '.', '?' });
if (dotIndex >= 0)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, dotIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: А можно в индексоф передать несколько знаков? Например если окончание предложение будет вопросительным?

Comment: да, добавил пример

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "string before dot. string after dot";
var result = s.Split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Жутко неэкономно по памяти, плюс если в коде много точек, выполняет кучу лишней работы.